# How to remove database id from url

Tags: content-management-system, coupon

I am creating categories on my website, but CMS adds ID from phpmyadmin to link. For example, I want to create category with name Art. When I do this system gives me like this link http://domain.com/category/art-2/ this 2 is my category ID but I don't wont this on my link. I want to be like this http://domain.com/category/art/

How can I resolve this?

Comment: I think it would be useful to know the name of the CMS

Comment: it's Coupon CMS 5.0 (codecanyon)